# force matplotlib to fix the plot area

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple plots that have the same x-axis. I would like to stack them in a report and have everything line up. However, matplotlib seems to resize them slightly based on the y tick label length.

Is it possible to force the plot area and location to remain the same across plots, relative to the pdf canvas to which I save it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs=np.arange(0.,2.,0.00001)
ys1=np.sin(xs*10.) #makes the long yticklabels
ys2=10.*np.sin(xs*10.)+10. #makes the short yticklabels

fig=plt.figure() #this plot ends up shifted right on the canvas
plt.plot(xs,ys1,linewidth=2.0)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

fig=plt.figure() #this plot ends up further left on the canvas
plt.plot(xs,ys2,linewidth=2.0)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Comment: You could plot them as subplots in the same figure?

Comment: The plots have the same size in both cases. Also the axes have the same size. It's not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a little unclear, however plotting them as subplots in the same figure should gaurantee that the axes and figure size of the two subplots will be alligned with each other

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs=np.arange(0.,2.,0.00001)
ys1=np.sin(xs*10.) #makes the long yticklabels
ys2=10.*np.sin(xs*10.)+10. #makes the short yticklabels

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax1.plot(xs,ys1,linewidth=2.0)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

ax2.plot(xs,ys2,linewidth=2.0)
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('y')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)  # adjust spacing between plots    
plt.show()
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The following works for me.

Force the same figure width for all your plots around all your python scripts, for example:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
...
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
```

And do not use (very important!):

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

Save the figure

```
plt.savefig('figure.png')
```

Plot areas should now be the same.

Answer (score 0):

using subplots with the same x-axis should do the trick.

use `sharex=True` when you create the subplots. The benefit of `sharex` is that zooming or panning on 1 subplot will also auto-update on all subplots with shared axes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = np.arange(0., 2., 0.00001)
ys1 = np.sin(xs * 10.)  # makes the long yticklabels
ys2 = 10. * np.sin(xs * 10.) + 10.  # makes the short yticklabels

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
ax1.plot(xs, ys1, linewidth=2.0)
ax1.xlabel('x')
ax1.ylabel('y')

ax2.plot(xs, ys2, linewidth=2.0)
ax2.xlabel('x')
ax2.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```